# Create mysql rows/columns

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I wrote a little ruby script, which connects itself to a mysql database and creates a table (if this table doesn't exist yet). After this the script should store content in this table I try to store this data using:

```
Table.create(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")
```

I also tried

```
Table.new(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")
```

but it seems to do the same because I always get the error:

> Mysql::Error: Table 'my-username.my-dbname' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM table-name

SO this is what I got so far:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
                :adapter => "mysql",
                :host => "localhost",
                :username => "my-username",
                :password => "my-password",
                :database => "my-db-name",
                :encoding => "UTF8"
        )

        table_name = "my_table"
        unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? table_name
                ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
                        create_table :"#{table_name}" do |table|
                                table.column :foo, :string
                                table.column :bar, :string
                                table.column :blallala, :string
                        end
                end
        end

        class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
                self.table_name = "#{table_name}"
        end

         Table.create(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")
         #Table.new(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")
```

So the question is: How do I actually create a columo/row and why does `Table.create(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")` not work?

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: The question is: How do I actually create a columo/row and why does `Table.create(:foo => "bar", :foobar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")` not work?

Comment: You can't create a table and at the same time insert data to it. It has to be two separate statements. So it's no wonder your first two samples don't work.

Comment: well I doesnt not even work when I insert sleep(42) before the Table.create or what do you mean by that? / What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# establish connection here

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "the_table"
end

unless Table.table_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :the_table do |table|
      table.column :foo, :string
      table.column :bar, :string
      table.column :blallala, :string
    end
  end
end


Table.create(:foo => "bar", :bar => "something", :blallala => "blololl")
```

Comment: Ah found the error (it was a typo) fixed it and it's working thanks dude :3

Comment: No problem. Pay more attention next time :)